# Unexpected key weight (int) under font

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to add the `Monserrat` font to my flutter app with the following code in the `pubspec.yaml` file.

```
  fonts:
    - family: Montserrat
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Montserrat-Light.ttf
          weigth: 200
        - asset: fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf
          weight: 500        
        - asset: fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

But by doing so I get an exception while trying to start the application:
`Unexpected key weight ((int)) under font.`

Only adding the Regular and the SemiBold with weight 700 does work. It are the light and medium ones that are causing the trouble.

Any tips on how to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the spelling of your `weight`.

It is `weight` not `weigth`.

I fixed it in the snippet below:

```dart
    fonts:
    - family: Montserrat
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Montserrat-Light.ttf
          weight: 200
        - asset: fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf
          weight: 500        
        - asset: fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

Comment: Daaaamn such a silly mistake. I just overlooked it! Thx for pointing this out.

Comment: You are welcome, you can accept the answer and upvote if it solved your issue. 